# Android: Attach SurfaceTexture to FrameBuffer

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, framebuffer, glsurfaceview

I am performing a video effect that requires dual pass rendering (the texture needs to be passed through multiple shader programs). Attaching a SurfaceTexture to a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES that is passed in the constructor does not seem to be a solution, since the displayed result is only rendered once.

One solution I am aware of is that the first rendering can be done to a FrameBuffer, and then the resulting texture can be rendered to where it actually gets displayed.

However, it seems that a SurfaceTexture must be attached to a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture, and not a FrameBuffer. I'm not sure if there is a workaround around this, or if there is a different approach I should take.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurfaceTexture receives a buffer of graphics data and essentially wraps it up as an "external" texture.  If it helps to see source code, start in [`updateTexImage()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/marshmallow-mr1-release/libs/gui/GLConsumer.cpp#198).  Note the name of the class ("GLConsumer") is a more accurate description of the function than "SurfaceTexture": it consumes frames of graphic data and makes them available to GLES.

SurfaceTexture is expected to work with formats that OpenGL ES doesn't "naturally" work with, notably YUV, so it always uses external textures.

Comment: Camera frame go into surfaceTexture, but what the exact format of the image frame?  When I draw the image to the surface of MediaCodec, why the encoder can encode the frame without format issue?

Comment: The system integrator must ensure that the graphics and video components interact. Android doesn't specify a single format, just that the GLES implementation and the video codec need to be able to share buffers. (Hence `COLOR_FormatSurface`, a/k/a `OMX_COLOR_FormatAndroidOpaque`... that's "opaque" in the data structure sense, not the alpha transparency sense.) This is not always automatic, e.g. GLES output to MediaCodec requires the `EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID` flag.

Comment: Do you mean the system integrator  must implement the external oes opengl extension?

Comment: The system needs to pass CTS, and interactions between graphics and video are part of the test suite. It doesn't matter who provides what so long as the pieces fit together in the final product.